# Override Swagger Attribute in A Reusable Controller

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm trying to implement reusable controller using class inheritance and decorators because I cannot find a good CRUD package for nestjs mongodb.

Now my problem is I cannot override some of the attributes from the controller using the reflect-metadata. example code below:

**Reusable controller:**

```
export class MongooseCrudController {
  constructor(
    public model: ModelType<{} | any>,
    public crudOptions?: CrudOptionsWithModel,
  ) {
  }

  @Post()
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Create a record' })
  create(@Body() body: CrudPlaceholderDto, @Query() query: CreateUpdateQueryDto) {
    const transform = get(this.crudOptions, 'routes.create.transform');
    const { populate = undefined } = query;
    if (transform) {
      body = transform(body);
    }
    return this.performCreate(body, populate);
  }
}
```

**Decorator to update some attributes:**

```
const CRUD_ROUTES = {
  create: 'create',

};
const allMethods = Object.values(CRUD_ROUTES);

export const Crud = (options: CrudOptionsWithModel) => {
  options = merge({}, CrudConfig.options, options);
  return target => {
    const controller = target.prototype;
    // get define DTO at decorator
    const methods = allMethods.filter(v => !!get(options, `routes.${v}`));

    methods.forEach((method) => {
      const types = Reflect.getMetadata(PARAMTYPES_METADATA, controller, method);
      if (types) {
        Reflect.decorate([
          // Update Dto
          Reflect.metadata(PARAMTYPES_METADATA, types.map((v: any) => {
            if (get(v, 'name') === CrudPlaceholderDto.name) {
              return get(options, `routes.${method}.dto`, options.model);
            }
            return v;
          })),
          ...get(options, `routes.${method}.decorators`, []),
        ], controller, method, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(controller, method));

      }
    });
  };
};
```

**Example application on above on controller**

```
@Crud({
  model: Menu,
  routes: {
    create: { dto: MenuDto, summary: "API to create menu" },
  },
})
@Controller('menus')
export class MenusController extends MongooseCrudController {
  constructor(public model: MenusService,) {
    super(model);
  }
}
```

Now I already achieved overriding the parameter decorator on **CrudPlaceholderDto**, byt I also need to update  **@ApiOperation({ summary: 'Create a record' })** summary value for it to have a proper name on every controller I used.

Answer (score 0):

can't you simply pass the specific description to the constructor, instead of hardcoding it in the MongooseCrudController class?

Comment: You cannot call it at the decorator parameter. Trying to achieve reusable controller for me not to repetitively input the description. What I'm trying to do is set the default description to class name and still allowing to override it.